# Резиновая верстка с одним фиксированным блоком.

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет.

Имеется верстка, блок с width: 100%. Внутри него 2 блока, ширина первого выстраивается исходя из изображения, которое лежит внутри него, ширина второго = 200px.
Это изображение также резиновое, оно может быть очень большим и сжиматься, а может быть маленьким и вообще не менять размер.

При этом нужно сделать так, чтобы второй блок был прижат к первому (они идут друг за другом).

Суть в том, что этого я добился, но задачу усложнил другой момент, если я внутрь первого блока после изображения добавляю еще блок, то начинается каша и все ломается, пример в [ссылке](http://jsfiddle.net/Ua58S/1/).

Сейчас если убрать второй блок в #left, все будет хорошо.

Прошу помощи, уже не знаю что делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ua58S/3/

Вкратце:

Добавляем

```
#right {
    ...
    margin-left:-100px; // ширина блока * -1
    }
#left {
    ...
    float:left;
    }
```

Comment: Супер, класс, спасибо огромное за подсказку. Очень благодарен